# Which pair of reindeer did Rudolph replace when he saved Christmas in the 1964 animated classic?

Tags: rudolph-the-red-nosed-reindeer

The song from the 1964 animated Christmas classic *[Rudolph the Red-Nosed Reindeer](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0058536/)* tells us about the eight reindeer that pull Santa's sleigh. There's Dasher and Dancer and Prancer and Vixen, Comet and Cupid and Donner and Blitzen. The song also introduces us to Rudolph, the most famous Reindeer of all.

What the song doesn't explain is why there are only seven reindeer hitched to Santa's sleigh when Rudolph saves Christmas. According to IMDb, there was a subplot about the missing reindeer that was dropped from the film.

Which pair of reindeer did Rudolph replace when he saved Christmas in the 1964 animated classic?

[image: reindeer pulling Santa's sleigh]

Comment: WTF, Santa's not Sci-fi or Fantasy!

Comment: Was someone playing too much Gem Miner 2 on their cell phone? (there's a side quest to find the missing Reindeer... in the mine of all places)

Comment: Rudolph is the ninth reindeer. Because of the available tv screen size in 1964, two reindeer were removed through the magic of editing.  Eight are required to pull the sleigh, anytime you see less than 8, you can assume you are watching altered footage.

Comment: What about the ninth and tenth reindeers, Olive and Andy?

Comment: Seems like a similar question to "why to cartoon characters only have three fingers?" with the answer being along similar lines.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to *Rudolph the Red-Nosed Reindeer*'s sequel, *[Rudolph and Frosty's Christmas in July](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rudolph_and_Frosty%27s_Christmas_in_July)* (1979), Rudolph replaced a Reindeer named [Scratcher](https://christmas-specials.fandom.com/wiki/Scratcher).

> Scratcher: Rudolph! Don't mention that name. I was all set to be one of santa's reindeer when he came along.
>
> Winterbolt: Indeed? **Santa fired you to make room for Rudolph**?

([Source](https://web.archive.org/web/20160111063542/https://tv.ark.com/transcript/rudolph_and_frosty%27s_christmas_in_july/4284/ABCFP/Saturday_December_12_2009/137569/))

As for the other reindeer, as explained in the other answer, they never existed.

Answer (score 5):

> Santa: "Well, let's hope so, if he wants to make the sleigh team someday. [to Rudolph] You see, little fellow, every year I shine up my jingle bells... for eight lucky reindeer."
>
> [Transcript from "Rudoplh the Red-Nosed Reindeer"](https://rudolphtherednosedreindeer.fandom.com/wiki/Rudolph_The_Red-Nosed_Reindeer/Transcript)

It seems to me the reindeer in the song are only the famous Generation 1 reindeer.  The film has Donner in a coaching role for the next generation competing for this role.  He is not hitched to the sleigh when Rudolph leads the team at the end of the film.

So asking why an 8 or 9 Reindeer team wasn't used in an emergency would be valid. However, there is no reason to assume any pair you can name were replaced.  The team for whatever reason had only 6 on the team and one can assume all were younger than Donner and Comet's generation.   Note also the other answer here mentioning Scratcher resenting being cut from the team - establishing further that year was a team of reindeer you haven't heard of.

Comment: This makes so. much. sense. The again, since Santa is (nearly) eternal, there's no reason his reindeer wouldn't be too.

Answer (score 3):

Well I can't say I have confirmed this, but [this Wikia on Christmas specials](https://christmas-specials.fandom.com/wiki/Rudolph_the_Red-Nosed_Reindeer_%28Rankin/Bass%29) claims to have:

> There are only six reindeer in addition to Rudolph, instead of the usual eight. It has been confirmed that there are only six reindeer because of the time that the creators had to make them, and because they were rather expensive to build.